# Which is generally best to use — StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase or StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase?

Tags: .net, vb.net, localization

I have some code like this:

```
If key.Equals("search", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
    DoSomething()
End If
```

I don't care about the case. Should I use `OrdinalIgnoreCase`, `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`, or `CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`?

Comment: Check this its really useful for this thread. My suggestion to use ordianlignorecase for comparison. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/noahc/archive/2007/06/29/string-equals-performance-comparison.aspx

Comment: Consider highly voted answer from the duplicate [String comparison: InvariantCultureIgnoreCase vs OrdinalIgnoreCase?](//stackoverflow.com/a/2749678)

Comment: Overall, it depends a lot on what kind of thing you're comparing. Specifically, if it's culture-dependent user input or internal stuff. You don't want the PC's culture messing up internal code string compares.

Answer (score 223, accepted):

**[Newer .Net Docs now has a table to help you decide which is best to use in your situation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/best-practices-strings#choosing-a-stringcomparison-member-for-your-method-call)**

From MSDN's "[New Recommendations for Using Strings in Microsoft .NET 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms973919(v=msdn.10))"

> Summary: Code owners previously using the `InvariantCulture` for string comparison, casing, and sorting should strongly consider using a new set of `String` overloads in Microsoft .NET 2.0. *Specifically, data that is designed to be culture-agnostic and linguistically irrelevant* should begin specifying overloads using either the `StringComparison.Ordinal` or `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` members of the new `StringComparison` enumeration. These enforce a byte-by-byte comparison similar to `strcmp` that not only avoids bugs from linguistic interpretation of essentially symbolic strings, but provides better performance.

Comment: To give an example where they differ, consider the two strings `"Straße"` and `"STRASSE"`. When using `OrdinalIgnoreCase` the `Equals` returns `false`, whereas `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` says they're equal.

Comment: This is wrong. `string.Equals("Straße", "STRASSE", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)` returns `false`

Comment: @wertzui the comparison returns `true` on my machine, running .NET 6.

Comment: What culture are you using? On my machine (Win 11, .Net 6.0.8, de-DE culture), I get the `false` for `CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`, `OrdinalIgnoreCase`, `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`. However `string.Equals("Straße", "STRAẞE", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase).Dump();` and `string.Equals("Straße", "STRAẞE", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase).Dump();` both return `true`. Note that `STRAẞE` is using an uppercase `ẞ` which was standardized in 2008.

Comment: Using dotnetfiddle.net, I only get a `True` for this example using .NET Framework 4.7.2.

Answer (score 73):

#### It all depends

Comparing unicode strings is hard:

> The implementation of Unicode string
> searches and comparisons in text
> processing software must take into
> account the presence of equivalent
> code points. In the absence of this
> feature, users searching for a
> particular code point sequence would
> be unable to find other visually
> indistinguishable glyphs that have a
> different, but canonically equivalent,
> code point representation.

see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence

---

If you are trying to compare 2 unicode strings in a case insensitive way and want it to work **EVERYWHERE**, you have an impossible problem.

The classic example is the [Turkish i](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_dotted_and_dotless_I), which when uppercased becomes İ (notice the dot)

By default, the .Net framework usually uses the [CurrentCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture.aspx) for string related functions, with a very important exception of `.Equals` that uses an ordinal (byte by byte) compare.

This leads, by design, to the various string functions behaving differently depending on the computer's culture.

---

Nonetheless, sometimes we want a "general purpose", case insensitive, comparison.

For example, you may want your string comparison to behave the same way, no matter what computer your application is installed on.

To achieve this we have 3 options:

1. Set the culture explicitly and perform a case insensitive compare using unicode equivalence rules.
2. Set the culture to the Invariant Culture and perform case insensitive compare using unicode equivalence rules.
3. Use [OrdinalIgnoreCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.ordinalignorecase.aspx) which will uppercase the string using the InvariantCulture and then perform a byte by byte comparison.

Unicode equivalence rules are complicated, which means using method 1) or 2) is more expensive than `OrdinalIgnoreCase`. The fact that `OrdinalIgnoreCase` does not perform any special unicode normalization, means that some strings that render in the same way on a computer screen, *will not* be considered identical. For example: `"\u0061\u030a"` and `"\u00e5"` both render å. However in a ordinal compare will be considered different.

Which you choose heavily depends on the application you are building.

- If I was writing a line-of-business app which was only used by Turkish users, I would be sure to use method 1.
- If I just needed a simple "fake" case insensitive compare, for say a column name in a db, which is usually English I would probably use method 3.

Microsoft has their [set of recommendations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973919.aspx) with explicit guidelines. However, it is really important to understand the notion of unicode equivalence prior to approaching these problems.

Also, please keep in mind that OrdinalIgnoreCase is a [very special kind](http://www.siao2.com/2004/12/29/344136.aspx) of beast, that is picking and choosing a bit of an ordinal compare with some mixed in lexicographic aspects. This can be confusing.

Comment: What if I'm building a Turkish app that will only be used by Turkish users but I want "ayakkabı" and "ayakkabi" to be equal, is there a way? When people type on their phones, most of them use English keyboard as default and don't care if they type "ı" or "i".

Comment: @VolkanSen - sorry for a late response, but you can make a string array and use `Contains`. `string[] validValues = { "ayakkabı", "ayakkabi"};` and then `bool isValid = validValues.Contains(input, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);`

Answer (score 4):

I guess it depends on your situation.  Since ordinal comparisons are actually looking at the characters' numeric Unicode values, they won't be the best choice when you're sorting alphabetically. For string comparisons, though, ordinal would be a tad faster.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want, though I'd shy away from invariantculture unless you're *very* sure you'll never want to localize the code for other languages.  Use CurrentCulture instead.

Also, OrdinalIgnoreCase should respect numbers, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Ever wrote VB6 code in a mixed-language environment? You can create code that compiles on a PC with the french locale but won't compile on PCs with the english locale, because any numbers stored in the form resources use the format of the current locale. I'd argue you need to take the opposite approach: be very careful when you use the current culture. Always think about whether your system will still work when its data moves between cultures. Same thing with timezones.

Comment: I do agree with the "it depends" answer. though not following the "respect numbers" bit?

Answer (score -1):

The very simple answer is, unless you are using Turkish, you don't need to use InvariantCulture.

See the following link:

[In C# what is the difference between ToUpper() and ToUpperInvariant()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550213/in-c-sharp-what-is-the-difference-between-toupper-and-toupperinvariant)

Comment: This answer may be simple, but it is also very wrong. The Turkish "I" is just an ***example***, there are many more possible pitfalls.

Comment: Yeah, in addition to Turkish there's Azeri. But that's it.

Comment: I mean in reality, is there really any point in solving problems you will NEVER have? The Science side would say yes, but in practicality its a wasted effort for 99.999% of implementations (and that might not be enough 9s)