# Relationship between StringComparer.OrdinalignoreCase and StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase

Tags: .net, string, localization, cultureinfo, invariantculture

I'm trying to get the relationship between results of string comparison when using `StringComparer.OrdinalignoreCase` and `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`. More precisely I would like to know which of the following four statements is true:

1. `a == b using StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`, then `a == b using StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`
2. `a != b using StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`, then `a != b using StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`
3. `a == b using StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`, then `a == b using StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`
4. `a != b using StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`, then `a != b using StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`

So far I know statement number 3 is not true because of the example of `a = STRASSE` and `b = Straße` from a comment in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72696/which-is-generally-best-to-use-stringcomparison-ordinalignorecase-or-stringco) question.

Ideally I would like to have an explanation why a statement is true or an example when it is not true.

Comment: I don't believe any of those statements to be true for all inputs. However, the result of the `==` and `!=` relations for any particular string is guaranteed to be stable because ordinal on the one hand is simply a comparison of an array of ushort values (except for case ignorance) and the invariant culture on the other is guaranteed not to change across cultures and .NET versions.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between Ordinal and Invariant collation is the difference between non-linguistic and linguistic collation.

In theory 1 should be true (it is if you do not ignore case) but the casing rules are different when you use non-linguistic casing and linguistic casing. The rest are false.