# Is String culture info important for comparison if the user will never modify those strings

Tags: c#, string, string-comparison, cultureinfo, hardcode

When comparing hard-coded Strings that the User will see but not modify/change, is the culture info important.

I would assume not, but I just want to be safe.

Example:

```
static void Main()
{
    string hardString = "IAMHardCodei";
    string hardString2 = "IamHardCodei";
    //Compare hardString and hardString2, ignoring case, 
    //and then do stuff based on that result
}
```

Comment: It's always important, even if the user doesn't see or modify it. It all depends on what kind of data you're manipulating.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque I added an example to be more clear. The values are hard coded in by me

Comment: What if the two strings aren't equal in say, Chinese? Not true here but depending on the strings it could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general recommendation for string comparisons when they are "programmatic only strings" (i.e. as you specified they are not usable or editable by the user directly is the: `StringComparison.Ordinal[IgnoreCase]`.

See this SO post (of which this is probably a duplicate): [Which is generally best to use -- StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase or StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72696/which-is-generally-best-to-use-stringcomparison-ordinalignorecase-or-stringco)

Comment: @VMAtm It always depends on the very specific implementation needs, that was why I prefixed it with: "The general recommendation". :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.invariantcultureignorecase.aspx) for the comparing

```
hardString.Equals(hardString2, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 1):

Culture rules are relevant even for hardcoded strings if you're relying on the default `CurrentCulture` when doing comparisons. Here's a textbook example out of the MSDN documentation:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US")
Debug.Assert("file" == "FILE".ToLower()); // Passes

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("tr-TR");
Debug.Assert("file" == "FILE".ToLower()); // Fails
```

With case insensitive comparison, your users computers in Turkey don't think `file` and `FILE` are identical, whereas in the US they are identical.